# GestureDetector do not work when touch container empty space in Flutter

Tags: flutter

This is my GestureDetector define in flutter:

```
return GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStart,
          onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
          onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
          child:
          Container(
            color: Theme
                .of(context)
                .scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
              16.0,
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () => launchUrl(item.link),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        item.title == "" ? "Comment" : item.title,
                        style: Theme
                            .of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .headline5
                            .copyWith(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () async {
                          Channel channel = await Repo.fetchChannelItem(int.parse(item.subSourceId));
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChannelPage(item:channel)),
                              //ProfilePage(username: item.author))
                        );
                      }, child: Text(
                      item.domain,
                      style: Theme
                          .of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .caption,
                      )
                    ),
                  ),
                if (item.content != "")
                  
                if (item.parts.isNotEmpty)
                  
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

this page shows some article content, but sometimes the article is very short and make some space in the button of page. In this situation, the GestureDetector gesture not work when drag the empty spaces of the page. I have read this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062264/how-to-make-gesturedetector-also-work-when-touch-empty-space-in-flutter`. and add this line in the GestureDetector:

```
behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
```

still not work, so what should I do to make drag event work when drag the empty spaces of this page? Now I am using `flutter Inspector` to check the widgets and found GestureDetector area are smaller than sub child's area container:

[image]

what should I do to expand GestureDetector effect area?

Comment: If you are using Android studio, you can use the` flutter Inspector` where you can see all the position of your widgets. From there you can see why it is not working. Not sure about others IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expanded the container area by setting the min height

```
 constraints: BoxConstraints(
     minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.9,
 )
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can make a try with another `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent`