# ontap not trigger on Scaffold body

Tags: flutter, dart

my example code is

```dart
      
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print("tap");
        },
        child: Center(

          child: Column(
 
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

but i can't trigger my onTap function by touch the screen.
is it any problem?

Answer (score 3):

`Center` only takes the space needed for its child, you should wrap it with something that fill the parent's space. One of the possible solutions is to wrap the center with a `Container` and put a `color: Colors.transparent` to it.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      print("tap");
    },
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Center(
          // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `InkWell` widget or add `behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque` property to your current `GestureDetector`

so the code will be

```
body: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
    onTap: () {
      print("tap");
    },
    child: Center(

      child: Column(

        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
          ),
          Text(
            '$_counter',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

use this link for reference
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062264/how-to-make-gesturedetector-also-work-when-touch-empty-space-in-flutter#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20behavior%3A%20HitTestBehavior.opaque%20property%20of%20GestureDetector%20widget%2C%20that%20helps%20to%20tap%20on%20the%20placeholder%20inside%20Container%20even%20if%20Container%20widget%20doesn%27t%20have%20any%20child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062264/how-to-make-gesturedetector-also-work-when-touch-empty-space-in-flutter#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20behavior%3A%20HitTestBehavior.opaque%20property%20of%20GestureDetector%20widget%2C%20that%20helps%20to%20tap%20on%20the%20placeholder%20inside%20Container%20even%20if%20Container%20widget%20doesn%27t%20have%20any%20child).